# How to install mssql driver for php

Tags: php, mysql, macos, odbc

I am using mac os high sierra 10.13.6 version and run mamp for PHP but I am not able to install MySQL driver for PHP 5.6 what will I do?

I have mac os I am running PHP 5.6.4 using mamp, I want to run an application that uses MSSQL I am unable to find any drivers for it. When I searched for MSSQL for PHP on mac os high sierra

Comment: MySQL and MSSQL are two entirely different databases.  Are you trying to connect to an Microsoft SQL Server or a MySQL server?

Comment: I am tring to install MSSQL driver but not able to do